# Confused about a Wikipedia explanation on primitive Pythagorean triplets

Tags: pythagorean-triples

Link to the Paragraph: "Proof of Euclid's formula"
[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple#:~:text=Proof%20of%20Euclid%27s%20formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple#:%7E:text=Proof%20of%20Euclid%27s%20formula)

In this paragraph (please read from 4th sentence for context), there's a statement as follows:

> As a and b are coprime, at least one of them is odd, so we may suppose that a is odd, by exchanging, if needed, a and b. This implies that b is even and c is odd (**if b were odd, c would be even, and c<sup>2</sup> would be a multiple of 4**, while a<sup>2</sup> + b<sup>2</sup> would be congruent to 2 modulo 4, as an odd square is congruent to 1 modulo 4)

How can be **c<sup>2</sup>** be a multiple of 4 and **c** be a multiple of 2?

My argument: If both **a** and **b** are odd, then there squares are congruent to **1 mod 4** and therefore **a<sup>2</sup> + b<sup>2</sup>** is congruent to **2 mod 4** (which is clearly not a multiple of 4).

Please explain this ambiguity.

### Edit 1: Extended argument:

We can agree that if both **a** and **b** are odd, then there squares are **odd (congruent to 1 (mod 4))** and thus the sum of squares is **even (congruent to 2 (mod 4))**

I get that they are they to prove that both **a** and **b** can't be odd using proof of contradiction, so the two contradictory statements that they provide us are:

1. If both a and b are odd, then **a^2 + b^2** is congruent to 2 (mod 4)
2. if b were odd, c would be even (how and why???), and c<sup>2</sup> would be a multiple of 4**

They are trying to show that one statement concludes that **a^2 + b^2** is congruent to 2 (mod 4), whereas c^2 is clearly a multiple of 4, i.e. congruent to 0 (mod 4).

But I want to know the arguments which would imply that c is even (using which they concluded there second statement)

Comment: They're doing a proof by contradiction that $b$ cannot be odd. If $b$ were odd, they've proved (by two different arguments) both that $a^2+b^2$ is $2$ (mod $4$) and also that $a^2+b^2$ is a multiple of $4$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: @GregMartin I get that they are using proof by contradiction, but I didn't see any argument which would imply that c is even and hence c**2 is multiple of 4

Comment: Since $a$ is already known to be odd, if $b$ were also odd, then $a^2_b^2$ would be the sum of two odd numbers and hence even; therefore $c^2$ is even and consequently $c$ is even.

Comment: @GregMartin But they straight forward concluded that c^2 would be an multiple of 4 (I guess they, for some reason which I need to know, concluded that c is even, and therefore c^2 is a multiple of 4), and I need to know they concluded that c^2 would be a multiple of 4

Comment: You can conclude that $c^2$ is a multiple of $4$ because $c$ is even, which is because $c^2 = a^2 + b^2$ is even if we assume that both $a$ and $b$ are odd.

Comment: @SammyBlack ok I get it. I completely forgot that they clearly assumed that **a, b and c** form a triplet. And if we assume both a and b are odd, sum of their squares is even. But as we also assumed that they form triplets, which implies that the sum of squares value is a perfect square and thus its positive root is also even.